# Telerik radgridview merge/group

Tags: c#, wpf, merge, telerik

I'm working on an small C# (WPF + SQLite) application where I'm implementing `RadGridView` from Telerik.
I want to merge all columns where is the same ID like in the table. Right now my data looks like this (this is my view).

```
╔════╤═══════╤══════════╤══════╗
║ id │ ime   │ surname  │ year ║
╠════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════╣
║ 1  │ Name1 │ Surname1 │ 1994 ║
╟────┼───────┼──────────┼──────╢
║ 1  │ Name1 │ Surname1 │ 1995 ║
╟────┼───────┼──────────┼──────╢
║ 2  │ Name2 │ Surname2 │ 1996 ║
╟────┼───────┼──────────┼──────╢
║ 3  │ Name3 │ Surname3 │ 1996 ║
╚════╧═══════╧══════════╧══════╝
```

And this is what I want to achive in my RadGridView.

```
╔════╤═══════╤══════════╤═══════╗
║ id │ ime   │ surname  │ year  ║
╠════╪═══════╪══════════╪═══════╣
║ 1  │ Name1 │ Surname1 │ 1994  ║
║    │       │          │ 1995  ║
╟────┼───────┼──────────┼───────╢
║ 2  │ Name2 │ Surname2 │ 1996  ║
╟────┼───────┼──────────┼───────╢
║ 3  │ Name3 │ Surname3 │ 1996  ║
╚════╧═══════╧══════════╧═══════╝
```

The solution and the problem is merge option who radgridview has. But it mergers all data who are the same value. And it looks okay but the functionality is bad.

It does what I sad but when I try to click the merged cell after double click it does this. (In this example I clicked surname1 cell)

```
╔════╤═══════╤══════════╤═══════╗
║ id │ ime   │ surname  │ year  ║
╠════╪═══════╪══════════╪═══════╣
║ 1  │ Name1 │ Surname1 │ 1994  ║
╟────────────┼──────────┤ 1995  ║
║            │ Surname1 │       ║
╟────────────┼──────────┼───────╢
║ 2  │ Name2 │ Surname2 │ 1996  ║
╟────┼───────┼──────────┼───────╢
║ 3  │ Name3 │ Surname3 │ 1996  ║
╚════╧═══════╧══════════╧═══════╝
```

[image: This is my radgridview, the red marked is where i double clicked, and the green cells are one who I want to not to merge + after clicking that row I want it to be selected.]

This is my radgridview, the red marked is where i double clicked, and the green cells are one who I want to not to merge + after clicking that row I want it to be selected.

Comment: to achieve this in telerik's asp.net ajax ui, I implement `ITemplate` and initialized the gridview using my object. I handled and also exposed (encapsulated with new EventHandler)  the OnDataBinding events of each control I used within my template.. I'm not sure how viable that is with wpf projects.. what does your markup and control ininitialization look like?

Comment: This is my xaml binding, I'm just sending for one row.
 `<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="50" Header="ID" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=article_id}" IsReadOnly="True"></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In their RadGridView documentation, telerik has this to say:

Selection is currently not supported for the merged cells. When selecting a row, all the cells except for the merged one will show as selected.